# EXTJS4.2, Sanity check on my approach. GridPanel and hiding columns if no data present for a specific field

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

This might sound a bit insane but looking for a sanity check on my approach.

I have a requirement on a gridpanel where if no data is present in the store for a specific field then I should not show that column...simple enough...

Now I was thinking that the best way would be is as follows, on the store, I would use store.find on the field

```
store.find('checkthisfield',/^[A-Za-z0-9]/, 0, true)
```

and search for a -1... the store could be quite large therefore not that efficient.

Any other suggestions???... is there any way to tap the store field and get a size or count (not looking for a totalcount on the store but on the field), perhaps?

I don't have anyone else to bounce ideas off... Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to call ajax, who fill your store. And in ajax you will return some code for example, and encode it. So basicly add checking if sql dont return rows return success false and decode in javascript..little pseudo bellow

```
if($query has rows) then
  $result['success']=true;
else
  $result['failure']=true;
echo json_encode($result);
```

So I would start thinking by this way like i said. I hope it can help you.